# Should we make Print css for mobile specific websites?

Tags: css, xhtml, printing, mobile-safari, mobile-website

Should we make Print css for mobile specific websites? Sites which are specifically built for mobile users and we have different site for desktop/laptop user.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't bother.  I don't know anyone who prints from their phone.  It would make more sense to me to invest that time elsewhere.